# Component not updating when Redux store is changed

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

When a component is rendered, I'm trying to fetch a list of games and print them on the page in an unordered list. The API call works correctly, and Redux Dev Tools shows the store gets updated, but the component isn't updating to reflect the changes.

**Component**

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import {fetchAllGames} from "../actions";

class Games extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.dispatch(fetchAllGames());
    }

    render() {
        const { games } = this.props;
        return(
            <ul>
                { games.map(game => <li key={game.id} >{game.name}</li>) }
            </ul>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => (
    {
        games: state.games
    }
)

const GamesList = connect(
    mapStateToProps
)(Games)

export default GamesList;
```

**Actions**

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const fetchGames = (games) => {
    return {
        type: 'FETCH_GAMES',
        games
    }
};

export const fetchAllGames = () => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        return axios.get('/api/games').then(res=> {
            dispatch(fetchGames(res.data))
        })
        .catch(error => {
            throw(error);
        });
    };
};
```

**Store**

```
import {combineReducers, createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import GamesList from '../games-list/reducers';
import UsersList from "../users/reducers";

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    'friends' : UsersList,
    'games': GamesList
})

const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));

console.log(store.getState())

export default store
```

**Reducer**

```
const initialState = [
    {
        id: 0,
        name: 'Test Game',
        publisher: 'Test Co.'
    }
];

const GamesList = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case 'ADD_GAME':
            return [
                ...state,
                {
                    id: action.id,
                    name: action.name,
                    publisher: action.publisher
                }
            ]
        case 'DELETE_GAME':
            return state.splice(state.indexOf(action.id), 1);
        case 'FETCH_GAMES':
            return [
                ...state,
                action.games
            ]

        default:
            return state
    }
}

export default GamesList;
```

Comment: Have you used e.g. the Redux dev tools to find out what actions are occurring and whether the state is updating? React dev tools to see what the props to the component are? Are there any messages in the console? Have you done any other debugging?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure how to set up Redux dev tools at the moment. I've done a few console logs along the way, so I know the data is being fetched for sure.

Comment: OK, so I've set up dev tools, and the state is definitely updating, so I will edit my question.

Comment: @ChrisWickham can you log  action.games ? shouldn't be  ...action.games??

Comment: So do you see the props to `Games` updating? To what? Again, any messages in the console when this runs? What markup gets rendered? If the state is updating **correctly** (is it?) then the [mcve] wouldn't need the Redux components at all.

Comment: Thanks @Roy.B - I needed the spread operator! :)

Comment: @ChrisWickham cool il write down an answer, glad I could help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to spread your results:

do it like this:

```
 case 'FETCH_GAMES':
            return [
                ...state,
                ...action.games
            ]
```